# Merge a branch twice into another

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

I want to merge a branch twice to another branch.
Let's say, I had a file in master branch.

Contents of src/File.txt

`ABC`

1. I've created 'fix' branch from master and updated the src/File.txt to `ABC - Fix`
2. I've merged 'fix' branch to master by merging the PR (fix -> master)
3. Now I've created 'feature' branch from master and updated the src/File.txt to
   `ABC - Feature`
4. I've merged 'feature' branch to master by merging the PR (feature -> master)

Now, I want to have `ABC - Fix` on my master branch. When I'm creating the PR fix -> master, Github is showing **There isn’t anything to compare.**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As per your question, in step 2 you have merged (fix -> master) so all those commits from your fix branch would be moved to your master branch. Thus, later when you are trying to raise another PR from your ABC - Fix branch, git shows "There isn’t anything to compare" as all the commits are present already.
2. However, if you must raise a PR again, then you need to have atleast one new commit in your ABC - Fix branch. If you don't have anything to change in the code at this point, you should try using this git command -

```
 git commit --allow-empty -m <message>
```

This will create a new commit in your ABC - Fix branch(without changing anything in code) for you to raise PR towards master successfully.